Oracle Linux Kernel cannot be set after OS upgrade
we have two physical machines running Oracle Linux and I was tasked to upgrade them from OL 7.9 to 8.10.
I already did this on the 5 OL VMs we have and it worked fine. The upgrade on the first physical machine also worked flawless.
But on the second machine, there was a problem and the kernel did not update.
Before and after, uname -r shows:
5.4.17-2136.332.5.2.el7uek.x86_64
On the first working machine, the new kernel is
4.18.0-553.5.1.el8_10.x86_64
The post-upgrade-leapp-report in /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.txt showed has a new risk factor that was not present before the upgrade (which makes sense, as it's about packages that were not upgraded)
Risk Factor: high
Title: Some OL 7 packages have not been upgraded
Summary: Following OL 7 packages have not been upgraded:
kernel-uek-5.4.17-2136.332.5.2.el7uek
kernel-3.10.0-1160.119.1.0.1.el7
leapp-upgrade-el7toel8-0.17.0-1.0.29.el7_9
libburn1-1.5.6-1.el7
dkms-3.0.12-1.el7
kernel-uek-4.14.35-2047.525.1.el7uek
dkms-3.0.11-1.el7
kernel-3.10.0-1160.90.1.0.1.el7
libburn1-1.5.4-2.el7
libisofs1-1.5.6-1.el7
xorg-x11-apps-7.7-7.el7
libisofs1-1.5.4-1.el7
kf5-filesystem-5.52.0-1.el7
Please remove these packages to keep your system in supported state.

Because I'm very new to Oracle Linux and there is not much OL-knowledge in the department, I hesitate to remove kernel packages because I don't want to break things.
Also, different readings show different sets of installed kernels.
sudo awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " {print $2}' /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg
Oracle Linux Server 7.9, with Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 5.4.17-2136.332.5.2.el7uek.x86_64
Oracle Linux Server 7.9, with Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 4.14.35-2047.525.1.el7uek.x86_64
Oracle Linux Server 7.9, with Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 4.14.35-1902.10.4.1.el7uek.x86_64
Oracle Linux Server 7.9, with Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 4.14.35-1902.3.2.el7uek.x86_64
Oracle Linux Server 7.9, with Linux 3.10.0-1160.119.1.0.1.el7.x86_64
Oracle Linux Server 7.9, with Linux 3.10.0-1160.90.1.0.1.el7.x86_64
Oracle Linux Server 7.9, with Linux 3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64
Oracle Linux Server 7.9, with Linux 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64
Oracle Linux Server 7.9, with Linux 0-rescue-cd0018bf682e49869f3e6b713b3d9d63

sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /dev/null | grep menuentry
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.17-2136.332.5.2.el8uek.x86_64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.17-2136.332.5.2.el7uek.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-5.4.17-2136.332.5.2.el7uek.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10.x86_64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.14.35-2047.525.1.el7uek.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.14.35-2047.525.1.el7uek.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1160.119.1.0.1.el7.x86_64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1160.90.1.0.1.el7.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-1160.90.1.0.1.el7.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-cd0018bf682e49869f3e6b713b3d9d63
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-cd0018bf682e49869f3e6b713b3d9d63.img

rpm -q kernel
kernel-3.10.0-1160.90.1.0.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-1160.119.1.0.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10.x86_64

sudo yum list available kernel*
Last metadata expiration check: 3:29:00 ago on Tue 09 Jul 2024 05:46:55 PM CEST.
Available Packages
kernel.src                                                             4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10                                         ol8_baseos_latest
kernel-abi-stablelists.noarch                                          4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10                                         ol8_baseos_latest
kernel-abi-whitelists.noarch                                           4.18.0-240.22.1.el8_3                                         ol8_baseos_latest
kernel-cross-headers.x86_64                                            4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10                                         ol8_baseos_latest
kernel-debug.x86_64                                                    4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10                                         ol8_baseos_latest
kernel-debug-core.x86_64                                               4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10                                         ol8_baseos_latest
kernel-debug-devel.x86_64                                              4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10                                         ol8_baseos_latest
kernel-debug-modules.x86_64                                            4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10                                         ol8_baseos_latest
kernel-debug-modules-extra.x86_64                                      4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10                                         ol8_baseos_latest
kernel-doc.noarch                                                      4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10                                         ol8_baseos_latest
kernel-rpm-macros.noarch                                               131-1.0.1.el8                                                 ol8_appstream
kernel-uek.src                                                         5.4.17-2136.333.5.el8uek                                      ol8_UEKR6
kernel-uek.x86_64                                                      5.4.17-2136.333.5.el8uek                                      ol8_UEKR6
kernel-uek-container.src                                               5.4.17-2136.333.5.el8                                         ol8_UEKR6
kernel-uek-container.x86_64                                            5.4.17-2136.333.5.el8                                         ol8_UEKR6
kernel-uek-container-debug.x86_64                                      5.4.17-2136.333.5.el8                                         ol8_UEKR6
kernel-uek-debug.x86_64                                                5.4.17-2136.333.5.el8uek                                      ol8_UEKR6
kernel-uek-debug-devel.x86_64                                          5.4.17-2136.333.5.el8uek                                      ol8_UEKR6
kernel-uek-devel.x86_64                                                5.4.17-2136.333.5.el8uek                                      ol8_UEKR6
kernel-uek-doc.noarch                                                  5.4.17-2136.333.5.el8uek                                      ol8_UEKR6
kernelshark.x86_64                                                     2.7-10.0.1.el8                                                ol8_appstream

When I try to install kernels with sudo yum install kernel it does not install anything new
Last metadata expiration check: 3:29:45 ago on Tue 09 Jul 2024 05:46:55 PM CEST.
Package kernel-3.10.0-1160.90.1.0.1.el7.x86_64 is already installed.
Package kernel-3.10.0-1160.119.1.0.1.el7.x86_64 is already installed.
Package kernel-4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

Therefore, I think, I should be able to set the 4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10.x86_64 as default, but when I try it with grubby --set-default /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10.x86_64 I get the error
The param /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10.x86_64 is incorrect
The method to set the default kernel, that worked before the upgrade
sudo grub2-set-default 0 for the first entry of 
sudo awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " {print $2}' /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg

is not working because the 4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10.x86_64 kernel is not in this list (as seen above)
Could you please point me in the right direction? I don't know what to do anymore

Verify and confirm: are the outputs of ls /boot/vmlinuz* and rpm -q kernel the same?

no, they're not. In rpm are 3:
kernel-3.10.0-1160.90.1.0.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-1160.119.1.0.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10.x86_64
in the ll are 7:
/boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-cd0018bf682e49869f3e6b713b3d9d63
/boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1160.119.1.0.1.el7.x86_64
/boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1160.90.1.0.1.el7.x86_64
/boot/vmlinuz-4.14.35-2047.525.1.el7uek.x86_64
/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10.x86_64
/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.17-2136.332.5.2.el7uek.x86_64
/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.17-2136.332.5.2.el8uek.x86_64

Update: could solve it.
There was only a .x86_64 version of the kernel present, but no .img. After building that with mkinitrd, I was able to set the kernel as default and after a reboot it is active.
Thank you anyways

@Jonas Please post an answer for future readers, and accept it.

sorry, I'm new and didn't know how to mark it solved. I posted the answer and will accept it in 5 hours when I'm allowed to. Thanks for the heads up

Update: could solve it.
There was only a .x86_64 version of the kernel present, but no .img.
After building that with mkinitrd, I was able to set the kernel as default and after a reboot it is active.
